# Replacing 1N4001 for higher current diodes

Tags: diodes

We're trying to build a PCB here which originally has several 1N4001 diodes but we only have 1N4007 or 1N4008 diodes.

What would be the consequences of such replacement? Are 1N4001 diodes more "sensitive" than the other ones? What would it be the difference in its specs?

Comment: What do the datasheets say?

Answer (score 1):

The 1N4001 diode is considered a general purpose rectifier. It's in a family along which includes the 1N4001 through 1N4007 diodes.

I have never heard of (and cannot find) a 1N4008.

You should look at [the datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf) for these diodes to determine if you can substitute them safely.

The main difference is in the maximum ratings:

[image: Vishay 1N4001-1N4007 Rectifiers]

You will have to make the determination of what constitutes an acceptable replacement because we do not know the characteristics of your device.

Comment: asuming the 1n4001 diodes haven't any backdrop currents. so the practical difference is maximum voltages. like if the circuit current is around 500mA with any chances of peaks to 1A it will simply be wrong using the 1N4001 instead of the actual 1N4007 on the schematics. thank you very much very nice.

Comment: [1N4008 datasheet](http://www.lrc.cn/data/pdf/1N4008.pdf)

Comment: Ah so the 4008 just continues increasing the max ratings. I guess Vishay doesn't make one, but LRC does.

Answer (score 0):

Hardly matters if you replace the 4001 to 4007 series.  It depends upon the reverse voltage and forward current.  There will be no change in the circuit if you replace the 4001 with the better one.  It would protect your circuit at high voltage otherwise.  If there is fast rectifier diode, then it creates some issue due to its switching properties.

Comment: Please actually try to spell things correctly. "u" instead of "you", and "ur" instead of "your" is ridiculous and stupid.

Comment: @connor Wolf Oh sorry Its my mistake Next time I will keep these things in my MIND.From my side i want to say Answer should be valuable not language

Comment: @ConnorWolf But why downrates??

Comment: Because next time is irrelevant. Fix your post **this time** (you can edit your posts). Incidentally, you are judged as much by the quality of what you write as it's content. If you cannot speak coherently, or be bothered to proofread your posts at all, why should I have any faith in their content? You obviously don't care about what you say.

Comment: @Connor Wolf Is it ok or not?

Comment: Linebreaks, and spaces between a "." and the next letter too. Seriously. Write and format like you're writing for a school/job assignment.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Donwrates because of answer or writing skills.

Comment: @SHASWAT  While I think that ConnorWolf is being a bit overly critical, he is generally correct in his opinion.  I gave you a +1 to counteract the downvote and to encourage you to continue to participate here on EE.SE.

Comment: @DavidKessner - I would be much less critical if this were a single instance of the issue. Everything SHAZWAT has written seems to be a giant blob of text, with no formatting.

Comment: @DavidKessner Thanks for the support.I think 'writing skill' doesn't matter if answer is correct

Comment: @ConnorWolf I support you thats why i edit my post so now what's the matter?

Comment: @DavidKessner I only want to know that is there any point i am missing in my answer or it is completed.If not what i am missing.If Connor judge my answer with my writing skills then it's another matter.I don't want to talk more on this topic3

Comment: Writing skill *does* matter. If you are a genius on something, what does it matter if you can't convey your thoughts? I will overlook minor things, but if your writing is a hopeless mess, I agree with ConnorWolf, the post must be improved before it can be considered valuable.